# Finding stationary points of $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2+\beta xy+x+2y$

Tags: derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

I am working on a problem which can be seen below. Part i) was fine but part ii) is causing me some issues. Now the First Order Necessary Conditions state that for the interior case, then $$\nabla f(x^*) = 0$$ which I have attempted to use to find $x^*$. Taking the derivatives of the objective function I get $$\begin{bmatrix}2x + \beta y +1 \\
2y + \beta x +2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ which I have solved to get $(y-x) = \frac{1}{\beta - 2}$. Now I am convinced that I am wrong here because this does not seem plausible.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me some hints.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got:
$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & \beta \\ \beta & 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\ -2 \end{bmatrix}$$
Let's perform one step of row reduction:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{1}{2}\beta \\ 0 & 2-\frac{1}{2}\beta^2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{2}\beta-2 \end{bmatrix}$$
The system has no solution if $2-\frac{1}{2}\beta^2=0$ but $\frac{1}{2}\beta-2 \neq 0$, so when $\beta=2$ or $\beta=-2$. The system has infinitely many solutions if $2-\frac{1}{2}\beta^2= 0$ and $\frac{1}{2}\beta-2 = 0$, which cannot happen.

When $\beta\neq 2$ and $\beta\neq -2$ we do one more step of row reduction:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\beta^2-4\beta}{4-\beta^2}\\ \frac{\beta-4}{4-\beta^2} \end{bmatrix}$$

You can now readily read the solution.

Comment: How do we have infinitely many solutions for the second case? I thought it would just be $\beta = 2$

Comment: @InvestingScientist in the second case $y$ would be a free variable, but it cannot happen, not even for $\beta=2$

Comment: For iii) is it simply a case of using the $x$ and $y$ found here? My initial thought was to substitute into the Hessian but the Hessian does not have any $x$ or $y$. Thoughts?

Comment: I would have said that for $-2 \leq \beta \leq 2$ then we have a global optima because the function is convex over this range. So outside this range we have a local optima?

Comment: Solved it, never mind! Essentially it is as I said, for $-2 \leq \beta \leq \beta$ then we have a global minima, because the function is convex and the hessian is positive definite. For $\beta$ otherwise we have a hessian with both positive and negative eigenvalues with imply a saddle point.